# Parsing HTML with python request

Tags: python, parsing, html-parsing

im not a coder but i need to implement a simple HTML parser.

After a simple research i was able to implement as a given example:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://URL.COM')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will create a list of buyers:
buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')
#This will create a list of prices
prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')

print 'Buyers: ', buyers
print 'Prices: ', prices
```

How can i use tree.xpath to parse all words ending with ".com.br" and starting with "://"

Comment: can you add html dummy snippet?

Comment: why do you need to implement your own?
just use [bs4](https://pypi.org/project/bs4/)

you need external libraries anyway so why don't use bs4 instead of lxml?

Comment: That is not how xpath parsing works - you parse using first the document structure, not contents! If the *"words  ending with `.com.br` and starting with `://`"* are actually links (`<a href="...">` tags), you can use xpath to extract all links, then filter the ones you want.

Answer (score 9):

As @nosklo pointed out here, you are looking for `href` tags and the associated links. A parse tree will be organized by the html elements themselves, and you find text by searching those elements specifically. For urls, this would look like so (using the `lxml` library in python 3.6):

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO
import requests

# Set explicit HTMLParser
parser = etree.HTMLParser()

page = requests.get('https://URL.COM')

# Decode the page content from bytes to string
html = page.content.decode("utf-8")

# Create your etree with a StringIO object which functions similarly
# to a fileHandler
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(html), parser=parser)

# Call this function and pass in your tree
def get_links(tree):
    # This will get the anchor tags <a href...>
    refs = tree.xpath("//a")
    # Get the url from the ref
    links = [link.get('href', '') for link in refs]
    # Return a list that only ends with .com.br
    return [l for l in links if l.endswith('.com.br')]


# Example call
links = get_links(tree)
```