# Is there a way to parse out HTML in a response from requests.get()?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using the `requests` package to get data from an API and see some HTML elements in the response data such as `<p>`, `</p>`, and `\'`, among a bunch of other elements. The return value for `response.encoding` is `utf-8` if that helps.

I'd like to parse out all the HTML values and just have a simple text value in the field. Is there a way to easily remove or parse all HTML elements in the response?

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788359/parsing-html-with-python-request

Comment: you might find `requests-html` helpful

Answer (score 4):

A cleaner way for the above requirement would be to use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Following should be your approach.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response = requests.get("xyz")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
```

After this, you have all the html in an object which is basically a collection of dictionaries and lists. You could traverse and fetch the value you need.

Comment: Thanks, this looks clean. What's the most appropriate way to convert `soup` into a JSON object like `requests.get().json()`?