# Parsing Post Requests in Python

Tags: python, api, python-requests, oauth, bearer-token

I'm new to a lot of API work and I'm currently working with getting a bearer token from an API. After doing the proper POST request I'm able to get it but I'm getting it in a format that I'd rather not have to work around. I just get a big string of JSON data.

```
import requests
import os
import webbrowser

CLIENT_ID = [Client_ID]
CLIENT_SECRET = [Client_SECRET]
REDIRECT_URI = [REDIRECT_URI]
RESPONSE_TYPE = [RESPONSE_TPYE]

params = {
    "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
    "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET,
    "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI,
    "response_type": RESPONSE_TYPE
}

endpoint = [this is the url endpoint]
webbrowser.open(endpoint)

code = input("Enter the Code: ")
print(code)

endpoint2 = "[endpoint without the code]" + code
token_endpoint = requests.post(endpoint2)
print(token_endpoint.text)
```

When executing this code and going through the steps I'm left with this:

`{"access_token":"[bearer token here}","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":7200,"refresh_token":"-[refresh token here]","scope":"read","created_at":[time created at]}`

This is a full string object since I'm passing it as "text." I can't get anything to print if I don't do that but I'm willing to change that to get the access_token object to be it's own variable that I can work with.

Any tips are appreciated. Thanks.
(note: sensitive information is just put into brackets)

Comment: You can use `token_endpoint.json()` to get a dictionary instead of text

Answer (score 0):

You can use `token_endpoint.json()` to get a dictionary instead of text, and then select whichever key-value you want.

If you ever get stuck on anything `request` based, your first stop should be their excellent [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) here, most of the times that would answer the question you had. Case in point, [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) is the section relevant to your question

Answer (score 0):

I've never needed to use *webbrowser*. I think `response = requests.post(url, data=payload_dict)` and `json_response.json()` will provide everything you need (cf. [requests documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/)).
For extracting specific elements via xpath this answer might be helpful: [parse html response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788359/parsing-html-with-python-request)